# recyclerview notifydatasetchanged change current view position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

i have recyclerview in this when i click on one element of row i am changing model value and calling notifydatasetchanged. but problem is ,i have 20 row and when user visible rows are 15-20 and user clicks on 20th row and i call notifydatasetchanged then list goes up say 13th postion and now 13-18 row are visible

```
  textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClick(view);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: i suggest that never call notifyDataSetChaged() from adapter,
every time you scroll getview() call everytime so there's no need to notify it
but you can call it from outside the adapter when you calling setAdapter()

Comment: so right what i am doing i have callback to my view where i am calling notifydataset

Comment: so i am click on 20th element i want to update 20th element and my prev click elemet thats y i am calling notifydatasetchanged

Comment: adapter.notifyItemChanged(position); if you know position

Comment: If you are changing 1 row (Model) at a time, use notifyItemChanged(position); instead of notifydatasetchanged. This may solve your problem.

Comment: no i am changing 2 row , so one is current click row and 2nd is prev clicked row

Comment: then use 2 times adapter.notifyItemChanged(position); adapter.notifyItemChanged(position - 1);

Comment: but even this will change my currentview and go up